# Returning enabled for logging when it's disabled on all sites

Tags: iis, powershell, logging

Remoting using this code:

```
$pssessIIS = New-PSSession -ComputerName <servername>
Invoke-Command -session $pssessIIS -ScriptBlock {
if ([System.Version] (Get-ItemProperty -path \"HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows     NT\\CurrentVersion\").CurrentVersion -ge [System.Version] \"6.1\") { 
Import-Module WebAdministration 
} else { Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration }
Invoke-Command -scriptblock { 
IIS:
Get-ItemProperty IIS:\\Sites\\'Default Web Site' -Name LogFile | select-object enabled }
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $pssessIIS
exit
```

It returns "enabled" both remote & TS'ing into the server and running the ps commands locally, yet, from the IIS mmc all websites have logging disabled and none are currently being written to.

So the question is why am I getting "enabled" from powershell IIS when all logging is disabled? Is it just reporting that it finds a logfile?

Answer (score 2):

Do you get the correct value with this?

```
(Get-WebConfiguration -Filter system.webServer/httpLogging -PSPath 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site').dontLog
```

Comment: Thanks Shay, worked, I think the other ways only check if a logfile is configured and not whether logging is enabled or or not.